# in app purchase is validating receipts on own server still necessary

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Had asked a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523482/preparing-for-in-app-purchase

As I did not want to mix an additional question in there - asking separately

Do I need to implement - validate receipts on my own using my own server ?
Was reading this link:
http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-a-russian-hacker-cracked-apples-ios-in-app-purchasing/

So am confused if I need to implement validating receipts using my own server or is this unnecessary

I am able to test in sandbox - basic stuff - but wanted to understand the details

Any pointers or suggestions would be welcome
Thanks
akila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your own server, yet jailbroken devices will be able to get your in-app purchase for free if they have the right package installed.

Comment: Thanks Domenico - so for non jail broken devices - not a worry - so again - is it worth it to implement your security on your own server ?

Comment: for bigger games, like bloons tower defense, clash of clans, yes it is, If your not making any money from your app it isn't worth it, if your making 200 dollars or more a month from your app, though, you may want to save up to buy one.